# Query to calculate term frequency * inverse document frequency

Tags: sql, oracle, tf-idf

I have 2 tables in my Oracle database:

1. `DF (term, doccount)`
2. `TF (abstractid, term, freq)`

One for Document frequency(DF) having terms and documentCount and another table for term frequency called TF havind the documentID, terms, Frequency.
I want to calculate TF*IDF where TF = number of times that a term appears in an article (frequency column from table TF) and IDF = log (132225)-log(docCount)+1

I want to store my result in a table (TFIDF) having documentID, Terms and the calculated TF*IDF

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join your `TF` and `DF` tables and then insert into the destination `TFIDF` table.
Try this:

```
insert into TFIDF (documentID, terms, tf_idf)
select abstractID, df.term, (log(10, 132225)-log(10, doccount)+1)*(tf.freq)
from tf, df
where tf.term = df.term;
```